# Async function won't return when the promise is resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following code:

```
let checkValue = async (nodeUrl, nodeName, value) => {

    let json = await getValue(nodeUrl, value);

    let obj = JSON.parse(json.value.information);

    for (let i = 0; i < obj.nodes.length; i++) {
        if (obj.nodes[i] === nodeName) {
            return Promise.resolve(true);
        }    
    }
    return Promise.resolve(false);
}
```

I tried to use `Promise.resolve()` to process the returned Promise value, but I still get `Promise { <pending> }` return. Why is this happening?

Comment: Just return `true` or `false` directly.

Comment: Because the return from `checkValue()` is a promise. Call `checkValue(...).then(console.log);` -> prints Boolean. As Johnny says, you don't need to resolve the promise.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I tried, but it won't work either

Comment: How are you calling this code?

Comment: @JohnnyHK I'm just calling the function `checkValue(nodeUrl, nodeName, value)` and expecting it to return `true` or `false`. Am I doing something wrong? Should I also use `await` to call it?

Comment: Yep, you need to use `await` to call it.

Comment: ALL `async` functions return a promise.  You will need to use `.then() ` or `await` after calling the function to get the value.

Answer (score 2):

Let's explain a bit what happens in an `async` function.

First off, all async functions return a promise.  Always.  You will always need to use `.then()` or `await` to get the value from the returned promise.

Second, Here's the sequence of events in your function.

1. You call `checkValue(...)` and pass its arguments.
2. The first line executes `await getValue()`.
3. This calls `getValue()` and receives a promise back.
4. Since you're doing an `await`, it suspends further execution of the function and, at that point in time, the the function returns an unresolved promise.
5. That unresolved promise is what you are looking at.
6. Meanwhile, the rest of your code after you called `getValue()` continues to execute.
7. Sometime later when the JS interpreter is done with what is was doing and goes to the event queue for the next event, it will find an event that leads to `getValue()` resolving its promise.
8. At that point, the resolved value from the `getValue()` promise is assigned to your `json` variable and the execution of the `checkValue()` function is unpaused and continues.
9. Then, depending upon the values in your `for` loop, your function will finish by returning a resolved promise.  Note, there is no reason to do `return Promise.resolve(true)` or `return Promise.resolve(false)`.  Just `return true` or `return value` is all that is required.  Whatever the `return` value is from an `async` function becomes the resolved value of the promise that was already returned from that function.  The interpreter does that for you.

> I tried to use Promise.resolve() to process the returned Promise value, but I still get `Promise { <pending> }` return. Why is this happening?

First, you get a promise because all `async` functions return a promise.

Second, it's unresolved at the time you examine it because the function was suspended at the first `await` and that's when the `async` function actually returned the promise and it is, at that point, unresolved because the function has not yet finished executing (due to the `await`).  See step 4 above.

Comment: @safqw - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.